# OneToMany Jpa keeps inserting duplicates in child table while parent table are being updated

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using `@OneToMany` spring data jpa annotation and my child table is being populated with duplicate values while parent table is figuring out there is already the same value there and it's being updated. How can I also update child table instead of inserting duplicate value, like it's done in parent table? Is there some property that can be added to `@OneToMany` annotation? This keeps happening every time I rerun the application.

Comment: Some questions: Do these entities have their IDs set? How are they persisted? How are you reading in this existing entity and its children? How have you set the relationship (ie is cascade merge set)?

Comment: Yes, they have their own IDs. They are persisted by implementing CrudRepository interface and then used its built-in save() and saveAll(). I'm getting the date from rest api and saving it to the db. the problem with children is that they are getting inserted in even tho the same row already exists in the table, while the parent table is being updated if the row already exists. I tried multiple cascade types.

Comment: do you have cascade merge set on the relationship? Show your code, but a solution might be to read in the children in the same context before the save calls on the parent